# unit testing asynchronous code and code without externally visible effects

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, testing

Actually, I have two questions, although a bit related:

- I know that unit tests should test the public API. However, if I have a close method that closes sockets and shuts down executors, however, neither sockets nor executors are exposed to users of this API, should I test if this is done, or only that the method executed without error? Where is the borderline between public api/behavior and impl details?
- if I test a method that performs some checks, then queues a task on executor service, then returns a future to monitor operation progress, should I test both this method and the task, even if the task itself is a private method or otherwise not exposed code? Or should I instead test only the public method, but arrange for the task to be executed in the same thread by mocking an executor? In the latter case, the fact that task is submitted to an executor using the execute() method would be an implementation detail, but tests would wait for tasks to complete to be able to check if the method along with it's async part works properly.

Answer (score 1):

The only question you should ask yourself is this: will I or my colleagues be able to change the code with confidence without these tests frequently executed.  If the answer is no - write and maintain the tests as they provide value.

With this in mind you may consider refactoring your code so that the "low level plumbing" (e.g. socket and thread management) lives in a separate module where you treat it explicitly as part of the contract that module provides.

Comment: not sure if it is even doable to refactor it like this. I already use executor services for thread management so they can indeed be replaced/mocked, and I am mocking sockets to test for example, if connect method properly calls bind with proper parameters. However refactoring to make this exposed, not sure.